# 「エラー: パッケージ ‘rJava’ をロードできませんでした」の表示

Tags: r

Rにて，.xlsxファイルを編集するため，rJavaをインストールし，library(xlsx)を実行したところ，以下のようなエラーが表示されてしまします．

```
> library(xlsx)
 要求されたパッケージ rJava をロード中です 
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
  .onLoad は loadNamespace()（'rJava' に対する）の中で失敗しました、詳細は: 
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) 
  error:  共有ライブラリ '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so' を読み込めません: 
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found  
 エラー:  パッケージ ‘rJava’ をロードできませんでした 
 追加情報:  警告メッセージ: 
 命令 '/usr/libexec/java_home' の実行は状態 1 を持ちました  
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
```

なお，実行環境はmacOS Sierra ver.10.12.5です．
当方，プログラミング初学者のため，至らない点等多々あると思いますが，ご回答の方何卒よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: Javaの実行環境が見つからないというエラーのようです。JDKはインストールされているでしょうか？[こちら](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/)のInstallationの手順も確認してみてください。

Comment: ご回答，ありがとうございます．JDKをインストール後，library(xlsx)を実行したところ，以下のようなエラーが表示されてしまします．

Comment: library(xlsx)
 要求されたパッケージ rJava をロード中です 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
  .onLoad は loadNamespace()（'rJava' に対する）の中で失敗しました、詳細は: 
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) 
  error:  共有ライブラリ '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so' を読み込めません:

Comment: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found  
 エラー:  パッケージ ‘rJava’ をロードできませんでした

Comment: 3行目と最後の3行以外は同じという感じですかね。rJavaのインストール手順は確認されましたか？[こちら](https://qiita.com/jjzak/items/470232f08bec4c4df02b)が参考になるかと思います。（特に「Rの設定」の部分)

Comment: またインストールしたJDKのバージョン(32 bit or 64bit)が不適切なために、このようなエラーが起こることもあるようです(https://stackoverflow.com/q/37735108/5546006)。お使いのOSですと64 bitになるでしょうか。`java -version`で確認できます。(Rについては`R --version`)